# JQuery .on() method not working with image click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to implement a nested gridview with expand/collapse functionality. My problem is that the jQuery click function is not working. The scenario is as follows:

jQuery:

```
$("[src*=plus]").on("click", "img", function () {
            alert('hi');
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
        });
        $("[src*=minus]").on("click", "img", function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
            $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
        });
```

GRIDVIEW:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Id" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Policy" HeaderText="Date" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Id" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Name" HeaderText="City" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Now, if I change the .on() method with the .live() method, then it works just fine. Any of you jQuery savvy people know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) correctly.

```
$("[src*=plus]").on("click", "img", function () {
```

This line means that it's looking for `<img>` tags as children of the selector `$("[src*=plus]")`

Since your image element is written like this `<img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />` you have two choices;

1) If your `<img>` is already present when the codes executes you can simple use

```
$("img[src*=plus]").on("click", function () {
```

2) If your `<img>` are created dynamically (example dom injection), you need to specify a selector that is already present. Something like this:

```
$("body).on("click", "img[src*=plus]", function () {
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the knowledge. So in my case in order fr it to work I had to put the code between `$(document).ready(function () {`. Now my problem is that it doesn't trigger the `$("img[src*=minus]").on("click", function () {` function. Instead it re-enters to `$("img[src*=plus]").on("click", function () {` and keeps expanding... Any ideas?

Comment: Ok; so I manage to solve the issue by adding an id tag to the image and refer to it by its id instead. Thanks so much for ur help.

Comment: @Dev Ngron - I am also facing same issue. Can you post some sample code on how you fixed that issue